# requested unknown parameter 1 for row 0 in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have below code for generating jquery datatable in my spring mvc project .
but i loading the page , the javascript throwing some warning.
[image]

```
 var sTable = $('#tblKeyDetails').dataTable({
            "aoColumns" : [ null,null, null,null],
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        });
    $.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getKeyDetails.html',
            data :({
                form : $('#ddlKeyStatus').val()
            }),
            beforeSend : function() {
                //startPreloader();
            },
            complete : function() {
                //stopPreloader();
            },
            success : function(data) {
                sTable.fnClearTable();
                  $.each(data, function(index,item) {
                     var rowCount = index+1;
        sTable.fnAddData( [ '<label align="center">'+rowCount+'</label>',
                                         item['key'], 
                                         item['date'], 
                                         item['userEmail']
                                         ]);
                    });

            }
        });
```

response  objects contain

```
date: null
deviceId: null
id: 3
key: "DQAIYLFFDVFG"
userEmail: null
userId: 0
```

Comment: you re adding a row with 4 colums when your table is configured with 3

Comment: Did you check the link given in the warning? It would have solved the problem ;)

Comment: but not found any solutions.

Comment: @vanojx1 thats my mistake , question updated.

Comment: @Andreas  they saying it is because of null data..In my case initially the data will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
sTable.fnAddData( [ '<label align="center">'+rowCount+'</label>',
                                         item['key'], 
                                         item['date'], 
                                         item['userEmail']
                                         ]);
```

to

```
sTable.fnAddData( [ '<label align="center">'+rowCount+'</label>',
                                         item['key']!=null ? item['key'] : "", 
                                         item['date']!=null ? item['date'] : "", 
                                         item['userEmail']!=null ? item['userEmail'] : ""
                                         ]);
```

preventing null values will fix your issue. You can also disable datables warning messages but fix the problem could be better.

Comment: var sTable = $('#tblKeyDetails').dataTable({
  "aoColumns" : [ null,null, null,null,{"defaultContent": ""}],
  "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
 });